# Disable Bing search entirely from IE when using sysprep

Tags: deployment, internet-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2, sysprep, waik

I'm creating a Windows Server 2012 R2 image for our product (an all-in-one appliance installed on server hardware) and I am having incredible trouble with getting Bing removed from Internet Explorer. Our clients do not want Bing at all, not as a default search, not as a "search from address bar" feature, not in any sense. I've managed to configure everything else that I want in IE using WAIK to generate an unattend XML file but this has me completely stuck. Ideally I want Bing removed from IE altogether but I would make do with it just being completely disabled. I can find no options in either WAIK or Group Policy to configure this as I need it.

Any ideas gratefully received.